# XSLT XML to HTML Crosstab table

Tags: html, xslt, crosstab

I am trying to make a crosstab tables from the XML file from ToDoList (http://www.abstractspoon.com/tdl_resources.html)  Here is an example XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<TODOLIST PROJECTNAME="Projects">
    <TASK TITLE="proj1" ID="1" NUMPERSON="1" PERSON="Chris" NUMTAGS="1" TAG="Caro" CALCTIMEESTIMATE="36"/>
    <TASK TITLE="proj2" ID="2" NUMPERSON="1" PERSON="Chris" NUMTAGS="1" TAG="Nat" CALCTIMEESTIMATE="8" />
    <TASK TITLE="proj4" ID="4" NUMPERSON="1" PERSON="Chris" NUMTAGS="1" TAG="Caro" CALCTIMEESTIMATE="36" />
    <TASK TITLE="proj5" ID="5" NUMPERSON="1" PERSON="Sahb" NUMTAGS="1" TAG="Nat" CALCTIMEESTIMATE="128" />
    <TASK TITLE="proj32" ID="32" NUMPERSON="2" PERSON="Seb" PERSON1="Chris" NUMTAGS="1" TAG="Nat" CALCTIMEESTIMATE="0.90" />
</TODOLIST>
```

Each task is an element and all the info are attributes.  I want to make a table like this with the tags as the top row and the persons as the first column.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Caro</td>
        <td>Nat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Chris</td>
        <td>72</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sahb</td>
        <td>128</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Seb, Chris</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see the same person can have many projects and I want to add up the CALCTIMEESTIMATE for each person based on the tag(s).  I can get the first row with

```
<xsl:key name="dtag" match="/TODOLIST/TASK/@TAG" use="." />
<xsl:for-each select="TASK/@TAG[generate-id() = generate-id(key('dtag', .)[1])]">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But the sum function does not give the desired results. What I'm I missing? Is there an easy way to do the sum based on two attributes?  ToDoList uses XSLT 1.0, that's why I couldn't use distinct-values.

Here is the full XSLT, I've tried alot of different thing, Here I was trying to get it working just for Chris but it would not add up his 2 projects.

```
<xsl:template match="TODOLIST">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
<html>
<head>
<title>Projects..</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<caption>Projects..</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
<td></td>

<xsl:for-each select="TASK/@TAG[generate-id() = generate-id(key('dtag', .)[1])]">
    <th scope="col">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </th>
</xsl:for-each>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<xsl:apply-templates select="TASK/@PERSON[generate-id() = generate-id(key('dperson', .)[1])]" />
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TASK/@PERSON">
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </th>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/TODOLIST/TASK/@TAG[generate-id() = generate-id(key('dtag', .)[1])]" />
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/TODOLIST/TASK/@TAG">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(../@CALCTIMEESTIMATE[../@PERSON = 'Chris'])" />
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to show the full XSLT you are using, especially the sum function which you mention that is not giving the desired results? Thanks!

Comment: I added my XSLT templates.  At first I did not have templates but I was trying lots of different things.  thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your sum to work, you need to know both the current person and the current tag.

In your current template that matches TASK/@PERSON, you should pass the current value of the attribute to the next template

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="/TODOLIST/TASK/@TAG[generate-id() = generate-id(key('dtag', .)[1])]">
     <xsl:with-param name="PERSON" select="." />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Then, in your template that matches @TAG, you could access the 'dperson' key in the SUM, so you sum all tasks for that person, and for the current tag, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="/TODOLIST/TASK/@TAG">
  <xsl:param name="PERSON" />
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of 
      select="sum(key('dperson', $PERSON)[../@TAG = current()]/../@CALCTIMEESTIMATE)"/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked great!  I knew it had something to do with the key.  I still need to figure out how to do the Sum when there are two persons ex.: <td>Seb, Chris</td>.  I will try more latter.  Thank you again.